# strip tags python

Tags: python

i want the following functionality.

```
input : this is test <b> bold text </b> normal text
expected output: this is test normal text
```

i.e. remove the content of the specified tag

Comment: Do you need this for any tag or just the example given?

Comment: @cb160 i want with any tag. i.e generic

Comment: Do you want it to strip all tags or just ones you list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
def removeTag(soup, tagname):
    for tag in soup.findAll(tagname):
        contents = tag.contents
        parent = tag.parent
        tag.extract()

s = BeautifulSoup("abcd <b> btag </b> hello <d>dtag</d>")

removeTag(s,"b")
print s
removeTag(s, "d")
print s
```

returns:

```
>>>
abcd  hello <d>dtag</d>
abcd  hello
```

Answer (score 5):

With BeautifulSoup:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup    
''.join(BeautifulSoup(page).findAll(text=True))
```

Found at http://www.ghastlyfop.com/blog/2008/12/strip-html-tags-from-string-python.html

Comment: @Brain i have already tried this one. but it just remove the tag not the content inside it.

Comment: @user283405. Hmm, make sure you use proper wording. I guess what you need is to remove content of an element (basically something starting with opening tag and ending with closing tag). Right?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah your example made that clear.  zoli2k's method also uses BeautifulSoup and is closer to what you intend.

Comment: With BeautifulSoup4 it would be `BeautifulSoup(page).get_text()`.

Comment: Actually I think REs are fine for this question. The reason REs can't, in general, parse HTML, is because you don't know how deeply the tags might be nested. In this question, we don't care about that - for any nested tags, we just match against the outermost open and close tag. The max level of nesting is 1.

Comment: @JonathanHartley: Not quite, since you may match a commented closing tag instead of a real one.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind Python (although regexps are fairly generic), you can take some inspiration from [Django's strip_tags filter](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/html.py#L57).

Reproduced here for completeness -

```
def strip_tags(value):
    """Returns the given HTML with all tags stripped."""
    return re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', force_unicode(value))
```

EDIT: If you're using this, or any other regexp solution, please keep in mind that it lets through carefully-crafted HTML (see comment) as well as HTML comments and hence should not be used with untrusted input. Consider using some of the beautifulsoup, html5lib or lxml answers for untrusted input instead.

Comment: Django's `strip_tags` filter is broken and close-to-useless. It's perfectly valid to put a `>` character in attribute values, and this doesn't even attempt to handle other markup constructs like comments.

Comment: Agreed (I've read the crazy question somewhere on StackOverflow trying to devise a regexp to parse HTML :). Personally on my website, I use lxml to do the same thing (as well as stripping prohibited tags and attributes). I think the above answer still has some valid usage when performance is important, but should only be implemented with those serious limitations in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
import re
input = 'this is test <b> bold text </b> normal text'
output = re.compile(r'<[^<]*?/?>').sub('', input)
print output
```

Comment: Regex + HTML = wrong. Essentially HTML, as it is (mostly) nested, is not a regular language, so cannot be correctly parsed by regular expressions. This is SOlore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You are definitely right; anyway it worked for the OP example ;).

Comment: As far as this question is concerned, we're not parsing the HTML (i.e. we don't care which parts of the text are between the 'open' and 'close' tags) and we don't care how deeply nested the tags are, so regex is a perfectly fine tool to use. (although it falls down due to '<' chars occuring other than in tags, as noted in other answers)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want `HTMLParser`. (`html.parser` in Python 3.)

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from sys import stdout
class Filter(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, ignored_tags):
        super(Filter, self).__init__()
        self.ignorelevel = 0
        self. ignored_tags = ignored_tags
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if self.ignorelevel > 0:
            self.ignorelevel += 1
        elif tag in self.ignored_tags:
            self.ignorelevel = 1
        else:
            # One of these two.  Test and see.
            stdout.write(self.get_starttag_text())
            #stdout.write('<' + self.get_starttag_text() + '>')
    def handle_startendtag(self, tag, attrs):
        if self.ignorelevel == 0 and tag not in self.ignored_tags:
            # One of these two.  Test and see.
            stdout.write(self.get_starttag_text())
            #stdout.write('<' + self.get_starttag_text() + '/>')
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if self.ignorelevel > 0:
            self.ignorelevel -= 1
            if self.ignorelevel > 0:
                return
        stdout.write('</' + tag + '>')
    def handle_data(self, data):
        stdout.write(data)
    def handle_charref(self, name):
        stdout.write('&#' + name + ';')
    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        stdout.write('&' + name + ';')
    def handle_comment(self, data):
        stdout.write('<!-- ' + data + ' -->')
    def handle_decl(self, data):
        stdout.write('<!' + data + '>')
    def handle_pi(self, data):
        stdout.write('<?' + data + '>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/ if you want to include some safe tags.

See the "Sanitizing Tokenizer" section at http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/wiki/UserDocumentation.

Remember to test for vulnerabilities if it's an important service: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html.

Answer (score 0):

Sam's answer should do what's wanted fairly well as far as I can tell, but it may pay to make sure that any left over <> characters are replaced with &lt; and &gt; respectively to prevent misuse/invalid HTML.

This approach has the advantage that it can accept incredibly malformed HTML references/tags. BeautifulSoup also handles malformed tags fairly well but html5lib, sgmllib and htmllib can choke on invalid code, some more than others if I remember correctly.

The following code also validates & HTML references:

```
import re
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint, codepoint2name

S = '1234567890ABCDEF'
DHex = {}
for i in S:
    DHex[i.lower()] = None
    DHex[i.upper()] = None

def IsHex(S):
    if not S: return False
    for i in S: 
        if i not in DHex:
            return False
    return True

def UnEscape(S, LReEscape=None):
    # Converts HTML character references into a unicode string to allow manipulation
    #
    # If LUnEscape is provided, then the positions of the escaped characters will be 
    # added to allow turning the result back into HTML with ReEscape below, validating 
    # the references and escaping all the rest
    # 
    # This is needed to prevent browsers from stripping out e.g. &#32; (spaces) etc
    re = LReEscape != None

    LRtn = []
    L = S.split('&')
    xx = 0
    yy = 0
    for iS in L:
        if xx:
            LSplit = iS.split(';')
            if LSplit[0].lower() in name2codepoint:
                # A character reference, e.g. '&amp;'
                a = unichr(name2codepoint[LSplit[0].lower()])
                LRtn.append(a+';'.join(LSplit[1:]))
                if re: LReEscape.append((yy, a))

            elif LSplit[0] and LSplit[0][0] == '#' and LSplit[0][1:].isdigit():
                # A character number e.g. '&#52;'
                a = unichr(int(LSplit[0][1:]))
                LRtn.append(a+';'.join(LSplit[1:]))
                if re: LReEscape.append((yy, a))

            elif LSplit[0] and LSplit[0][0] == '#' and LSplit[0][1:2].lower() == 'x' and IsHex(LSplit[0][2:]):
                # A hexadecimal encoded character
                a = unichr(int(LSplit[0][2:].lower(), 16)) # Hex -> base 16
                LRtn.append(a+';'.join(LSplit[1:]))
                if re: LReEscape.append((yy, a))

            else: LRtn.append('&%s' % ';'.join(LSplit))
        else: LRtn.append(iS)
        xx += 1
        yy += len(LRtn[-1])
    return ''.join(LRtn)

def ReEscape(LReEscape, S, EscFn):
    # Re-escapes the output of UnEscape to HTML, ensuring e.g. &#32; 
    # is turned back again and isn't stripped at a browser level
    L = []
    prev = 0
    for x, c in LReEscape:
        if x != prev:
            L.append(EscFn(S[prev:x]))

        o = ord(c)
        if o in codepoint2name:
            L.append('&%s;' % codepoint2name[o])
        else: L.append('&#%s;' % o)
        prev = x+len(c)
    L.append(EscFn(S[prev:]))
    return ''.join(L)

def escape(value):
    # Escape left over <>& tags
    value = value.replace('&', '&amp;')
    value = value.replace('>', '&gt;')
    value = value.replace('<', '&lt;')
    return value

def strip_tags(value):
    # Strip HTML tags
    value = re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', value)
    print 'No Tags:', value

    # Validate & references
    LReEscape = []
    value = UnEscape(value, LReEscape)
    value = ReEscape(LReEscape, value, EscFn=escape)
    print 'References Validated:', value
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Outputs:
    #  No Tags: this is test  bold text  normal text >< &blah &amp; &amp
    #  References Validated: this is test  bold text  normal text &gt;&lt; &amp;blah &amp; &amp;
    strip_tags('this is test <b> bold text </b> normal text >< &blah &amp; &amp')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working code taken from my project [Supybot](http://sf.net/projects/supybot/), so it's fairly well tested:

```
class HtmlToText(sgmllib.SGMLParser):
    """Taken from some eff-bot code on c.l.p."""
    entitydefs = htmlentitydefs.entitydefs.copy()
    entitydefs['nbsp'] = ' '
    def __init__(self, tagReplace=' '):
        self.data = []
        self.tagReplace = tagReplace
        sgmllib.SGMLParser.__init__(self)

    def unknown_starttag(self, tag, attr):
        self.data.append(self.tagReplace)

    def unknown_endtag(self, tag):
        self.data.append(self.tagReplace)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.data.append(data)

    def getText(self):
        text = ''.join(self.data).strip()
        return normalizeWhitespace(text)

def htmlToText(s, tagReplace=' '):
    """Turns HTML into text.  tagReplace is a string to replace HTML tags with.
    """
    x = HtmlToText(tagReplace)
    x.feed(s)
    return x.getText()
```

As the docstring notes, it originated with Fredrik Lundh, not me.  As they say, great authors steal :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the webob.exc module:

```
from webob.exc import strip_tags
```

And then use it:

```
print strip_tags('a<br/>b')
>> ab
```