# Replace HTML links with text

Tags: python, html, parsing, text-parsing

How to replace links with anchors in html (python)?

for example input:

```
 <p> Hello <a href="http://example.com">link text1</a> and <a href="http://example.com">link text2</a> ! </p>
```

i want at result with saved p tag (just a tag remove):

```
<p>
Hello link text1 and link text2 ! 
</p>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm guessing it involves BeautifulSoup :-)

Comment: @mgilson, won't a simple regex solve non-nested anchors case, will it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584885/strip-tags-python

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with a simple regex and the `sub` function:

```
import re

text = '<p> Hello <a href="http://example.com">link text1</a> and <a href="http://example.com">link text2</a> ! </p>'
pattern =r'<(a|/a).*?>'

result = re.sub(pattern , "", text)

print result
'<p> Hello link text1 and link text2 ! </p>'
```

This code replaces all occuring `<a..>` and `</a>` tags with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a perfect case for BeautifulSoup's [`unwrap()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = '''<p> Hello <a href="http://example.com">link text1</a> and <a href="http://example.com">link text2</a> ! </p>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
p_tag = soup.find('p')
for _ in p_tag.find_all('a'):
    p_tag.a.unwrap()
print p_tag
```

This gives:

```
<p> Hello link text1 and link text2 ! </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parser Library for it.. like BeautifulSoup and other also. I am not sure for it, but you can get something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727535/replace-urls-in-text-with-links-to-urls)