# Extracting text from html tags with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some html page to scrape data from.
So I need to get item title like here: 'Caliper Ring'.
I'm getting data from tag where that title appears:

```
item_title = base_page.find_all('h1', class_='itemTitle')
```

It contains these tags structure:

```
> [<h1 class="itemTitle"> <div class="l1">Caliper</div>
>                                 Ball
>                             </h1>]
```

To extract 'Caliper Ball' I`m using

```
    collector = []
    for _ in item_title:
        collector.append(_.text)
```

so I`m getting such ugly output in collector list:

```
[u"\nCaliper\r\n                                Ball\r\n                            "]
```

How can I make output clear like here "Caliper Ball"

Comment: This is similliar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157298/replace-html-links-with-text.

Comment: did you want the output in list?

Comment: @AvinashRaj doesnt metter, string is the best

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `regex`. You're adding too much overhead for something simple. `BeautifulSoup4` already has something for this called `stripped_strings`. See my code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

html = """[<h1 class="itemTitle"> <div class="l1">Caliper</div>
                               Ball
                           </h1>]"""
soup = bsoup(html)
soup.prettify()

item = soup.find("h1", class_="itemTitle")
base =  list(item.stripped_strings)
print " ".join(base)
```

Result:

```
Caliper Ball
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Explanation: `stripped_strings` basically gets all the text inside a specified tag, strips them of all the spaces, line breaks, what have you. It returns a generator, which we can catch with `list` so it returns a list instead. Once it's a list, it's just a matter of using `" ".join`.

Let us know if this helps.

PS: Just to correct myself -- there's actually no need to use `list` on the result of `stripped_strings`, but it's better to show the above as such so it's explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will help you to get the output(`Caliper Ball`),

```
import re
str="""[<h1 class="itemTitle"> <div class="l1">Caliper</div>
                                 Ball 
                             </h1>]"""
regex = r'.*>([^<]*)<\/div>\s*\n\s*(\w*).*'
match = re.findall(regex, str)
new_data = (' '.join(w) for w in match)
print ''.join(new_data) # => Caliper Ball
```

Comment: I have done it withot regex:
' '.join(word for word in _.text.split())

Answer (score 0):

you can use **replace()** method to replace **\n** and **\r** with nothing or space and after this use method **trim()** to remvoe spaces.